On causality for space-like intervals and the Klein-Gordon field: integral pg 27 of Peskin and Schroeder's Introduction to Quantum Field Theory
Note: this is not a duplicate: I am not interested in the issue of the contour, but in methods of integration.
I am desirous to integrate the following:
$$\int_m^{\infty}{\rho e^{-\rho r}\over\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}}\; d\rho.$$
This integral occurs in the context of the authors' proof that the free Klein Gordon field theory is causal, i.e. it is the transition amplitude for space-like intervals. In an attempt to integrate, I have done the following:
$$\begin{align}\int{\rho e^{-\rho r}\over\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}}\;d\rho &=\int 2e^{-\rho r}{d\over d\rho}\bigg(\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}\bigg)\;d\rho\cr &=2e^{-\rho r}\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}+\int2re^{-\rho r}\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}\;d\rho,\end{align}$$
where an integration by parts has been performed. Here is where I am stuck, I can find no integrable in my table that would allow me to go further. According to research on the topic, the integration can be accomplished in terms of Bessel functions, however, how does one get from the integral all the way to Bessel functions?

however, how am I supposed to know that? --seems to be an off-topic question.

Your v2 is now a duplicate of: this. There are plenty of questions here regarding this specific issue (i.e. KG propagator, Bessel functions etc.).

@TobiasFünke Well, how do you find them I only found one post about this integral as concerns analytic continuation.

Either use a software package like Mathematica that can handle symbolic integration (but make sure you understand what it's doing under the hood since it can make different assumptions about things like branch cuts than you would make), or use a comprehensive integration table like Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.

What do you mean with find them?? I just searched for "bessel function qft".

@TobiasFünke I do not see any way to search SE, I have been meaning to ask in meta about that, however, all I know is that when you attempt to ask a question; similar questions will pop up.

What? There is a search bar?! It literally says: "Search on Physics..." You can search for words, users, comments, tag etc. There are also more advanced search in the SE data explorer tool (I don't have a link right now).

@TobiasFünke I have surely never seen any search bar.

Sorry, but this is a problem totally on your side. I don't mean to be rude, but really this is a non-issue for the main site. It should be right next to your profile picture (left to it). If you don't see it, try a different browser, to start with.

Please consider revising your title, as it currently stands it is only indicating the source of your problem and does not describe what your problem actually is (and even the source of the problem is barely even meaningful to those that have the textbook).

I second the comment by @KyleKanos. It is not clear what kind of answer you expect, apart from "yes, it is a Bessel function, which you see after dealing with it several times, in, say, exercises". If you want to better understand the integral (its mathematical aspects) and not the physics, consider to ask on Math SE.

@TobiasFünke Yes. I will vote to close the question.

There is a natural subsititution $\rho = m\cosh t$ that will turn the integral into the standard  integral for the Bessel $K$ function:
$$
\int_0^\infty \cosh \alpha t e^{-mr \cosh t} dt= K_\alpha(m\rho).
$$

So, would this be evident if I were to study the properties of Bessel functions?

Yes. It is one of the standard special functions and is usualy covered in math courses for physics. You should  know that intergrals of exponentials of  sin, cos, sinh, or cosh, are Bessel functions.

Thanks, I knew that I could write the integrand as an exponential of a trigonometric function, but was not aware of their connection to Bessel functions, and my CRC table of integrals does not list such integrals. I need to invest in Gradsteyn and Ryzhik. time to start studying Bessel functions.
